# Unable To Deploy SSRS 2012 Report

Tags: ssrs-2012

When trying to deploy a 10mb report on SSRS I get the following error -

> Error  1   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.    at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()    at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)       0   0

I've done quite a bit of research on this and from what I've found, the only way to fix this is to change the web.config file. The problem is that I've done this and I still can't get it to work. We have SSRS2012 installed in Sharepoint mode so the`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer` folder does not exist. I did find the web.config file in the following location though - `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\WebServices\Reporting`. I changed the following line to

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000"  maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

but this still does not work. I also found a web.config file in the following location - `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebServices\Reporting` and changed the file as above as well, but still no joy. Are there any other config-files I'm supposed to be changing?

Comment: Can you please share what you have provided in TargetDatasetFolder, TargetReportFolder.....?(may be the format)

Comment: TargetDatasetFolder - Datasets & TargetReportFolder - Sales Reports. I have 2 other smaller reports in the same project which deploy just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying reports to SharePoint (as you have installed with sharepoint mode), then you must be having the URL for SharePoint path.

If you have the URLs, Try below:

```
TargetServerURL: put the sharepoint URL (Example: https://sharepoint.com)
TargetDatasetFolder: Path for your folder in SP. (https://sharepoint.com/MyFolder)
TargetReportFolder: Path for your folder in SP. (https://sharepoint.com/MyFolder)
TargetReportPartFolder: Path for your folder in SP. (https://sharepoint.com/MyFolder)
TargetDataSourceFolder: Path for your folder in SP. (https://sharepoint.com/MyFolder)
```

For Help - [Refer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283155.aspx)

Comment: We not deploying to Sharepoint just yet. Simply trying to deploy to Reporting Services. Only stated the Sharepoint mode because the directory structure of the install is different (I'm assuming). Alot of the posts say that all you need to do to fix the problem is change the web.config file in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer folder. We don't have this folder

Comment: Not sure if you should find it with SP mode. Anyway, If you change the web.config, then what? where the report will be deployed?

Comment: http://localhost/ReportServer. This is where all our reports are being deployed to right now.

Comment: This is the target path where SSRS installed with native mode.

Comment: Probably. Works for us for now though.